# When merging tif-files - set crs to EPSG:25833 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N

Tags: coordinate-system, merge, rasterio

When mering tif-files using rasterio merge, i need to set the crs to be EPSG:25833 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N. CRS are read using QGIS -> properties.

I use the script below, and it gives me EPSG:8687 - Slovenia 1996 / UTM zone 33N.

The code is based on https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC/notebooks/L5/raster-mosaic.html

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
import rasterio
from rasterio import Affine
from rasterio import windows
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
#File paths
dirpath = "C:\Python\Raster\Mosaic"
out_fp = os.path.join(dirpath, "Mosaic.tif")

#Select the tif files
search_criteria = "d*.tif"
q = os.path.join(dirpath, search_criteria)
print(q)
C:\Python\Raster\Mosaic\d*.tif

dem_fps = glob.glob(q)

#List fileds:
dem_fps
['C:\\Python\\Raster\\Mosaic\\dtm1_33_103_117.tif',
'C:\\Python\\Raster\\Mosaic\\dtm1_33_103_118.tif']

sources = [rasterio.open(raster) for raster in dem_fps]

memmap_file = os.path.join(mkdtemp(), 'test.mymemmap')
first = sources[0]
first_res = first.res
dtype = first.dtypes[0]

# Determine output band count
output_count = first.count
# Extent of all inputs
# scan input files
xs = []
ys = []
for src in sources:
    left, bottom, right, top = src.bounds
    xs.extend([left, right])
    ys.extend([bottom, top])
dst_w, dst_s, dst_e, dst_n = min(xs), min(ys), max(xs), max(ys)

out_transform = Affine.translation(dst_w, dst_n)
# Resolution/pixel size
res = first_res
out_transform *= Affine.scale(res[0], -res[1])
# Compute output array shape. We guarantee it will cover the output
# bounds completely
output_width = int(math.ceil((dst_e - dst_w) / res[0]))
output_height = int(math.ceil((dst_n - dst_s) / res[1]))
# Adjust bounds to fit
dst_e, dst_s = out_transform * (output_width, output_height)
# create destination array
# destination array shape
shape = (output_height, output_width)
# dest = np.zeros((output_count, output_height, output_width), dtype=dtype)
# Using numpy.memmap to create arrays directly mapped into a file
dest_array = np.memmap(memmap_file, dtype=dtype,
                   mode='w+', shape=shape)

dest_profile = {
    "driver": 'GTiff',
    "height": dest_array.shape[0],
    "width": dest_array.shape[1],
    "count": output_count,
    "dtype": dest_array.dtype,
    "crs": "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ",
    "transform": out_transform
}
# open output file in write/read mode and fill with destination mosaick array
with rasterio.open(
    os.path.join(r'C:\Python\Raster\Mosaic', 'test.tif'),
    'w+',
    **dest_profile
) as mosaic_raster:
    for src in sources:
        for ji, src_window in src.block_windows(1):

           print(ji)
           r = src.read(1, window=src_window)
            # store raster nodata value
            nodata = src.nodatavals[0]
            # replace zeros with nan
            r[r == nodata] = np.nan
            # convert relative input window location to relative output 
window location
           # using real world coordinates (bounds)
           src_bounds = windows.bounds(
               src_window, transform=src.profile["transform"])
            dst_window = windows.from_bounds(
                *src_bounds, transform=mosaic_raster.profile["transform"])

           # round the values of dest_window as they can be float
           dst_window = windows.Window(round(dst_window.col_off), round(
               dst_window.row_off), round(dst_window.width), 
round(dst_window.height))
            # before writing the window, replace source nodata with dest 
nodata as it can already have been written (e.g. another adjacent country)
            # https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590909/1979665
            dest_pre = mosaic_raster.read(1, window=dst_window)
            mask = (np.isnan(r))
            r_mod = np.copy(r)
            r_mod[mask] = dest_pre[mask]
            mosaic_raster.write(r_mod, 1, window=dst_window)

os.remove(memmap_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

The both coordinate systems are essentially the same despite the name and the code. The software you are using obviously selects the first coordinate system that matches the proj string and shows that.

```
projinfo -o proj epsg:8687
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs

projinfo -o proj epsg:25833
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
```

You must define the coordinate system not by proj string but with EPSG code or OGC WKT to include also the name. The WKT strings are as follows.

```
WKT2_2018 string:
PROJCRS["Slovenia 1996 / UTM zone 33N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Slovenia 1996",
        DATUM["Slovenia Geodetic Datum 1996",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4765]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Slovenia"],
        BBOX[45.42,13.38,46.88,16.61]],
    ID["EPSG",8687]]



WKT2_2018 string:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Europe - 12┬░E to 18┬░E and ETRS89 by country"],
        BBOX[46.4,12,84.01,18.01]],
    ID["EPSG",25833]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Would it be possible to change from epsg:8687 to epsg:25833?

Comment: I don't know r but something like `"crs":  "+init=epsg:25833"` might work.